# C# Polly WaitAndRetry policy for function retry

Tags: c#, async-await, polly, retry-logic

I'm very new to C# coding and I just want to know how to setup polly WaitAndRetry for my function if it failed. Following is my steps

1. I installed package  Install-Package Polly, using NuGet package
2. added **using polly** in my code.
3. Below is my code

```
public async Task<string> ConfigInsert(config model)
{
    try
    {
        SendToDatabase(model);

        await Policy.Handle<Exception>()
            .RetryAsync(NUMBER_OF_RETRIES)
            .ExecuteAsync(async () =>
                await SendToDatabase(model))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    } 
    Catch(Exception e)
    {
        _log.write("error occurred");
    }
        
    public async Task<string> SendToDataBase(config model)
    {
        var ss = DataBase.PostCallAsync(model)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
        return ss;
    }
}
```

But this call is continuously calling without any delay. I tried to use WaitAndRetryAsync in catch call but it's not working. WaitAndRetryAsync accepts only HTTP repose message. I want to implement ait and retry option in try-catch

Comment: I'm not hugely familiar with Polly but isn't the point of it, that you can not bother about the whole try catch like you have here you just confiugre polly (maybe like you have maybe not) and then call it, Polly handles failures and reties and if it works the first time then great it will return the result

Comment: ok thanks .i will remove  try catch

Comment: @junealex Please try to avoid to use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Please prefer `await` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you want WaitAndRetry but you don't use that function... And it doesn't only work with HttpResponse. Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#wait-and-retry).

The code below should give you a head start:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // define the policy using WaitAndRetry (try 3 times, waiting an increasing numer of seconds if exception is thrown)
        var policy = Policy
          .Handle<Exception>()
          .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
          {
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
          });

        // execute the policy
        await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await SendToDatabase());

    }

    static async Task SendToDatabase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("trying to send to database");
        await Task.Delay(100);
        throw new Exception("it failed!");
    }
}
```

Comment: no try catch required right ?.Also how to store the return value in  ExecuteAsync? var info =        await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await SendToDatabase());
this way right ?

Comment: The policy only handles exceptions thrown by the execute delegate while it is retrying. If the final retry attempt fails  then an exception will be thrown, so you may still want the try catch around `ExecuteAsync` to handle this scenario. See [the docs](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#how-polly-retry-works) for an explanation.